# How do I fix a "Broken Pipe" error when using a Canon printer?

Tags: printing, canon

I just started to use a [Canon Pixma MG2550](http://www.canon-europe.com/Printers/Inkjet/PIXMA/PIXMA_MG2550/) printer. It did about 8 print outs then stopped. I get the message 'Broken Pipe.' Also the printer queue is deleted or says 'processing' and all sorts of fanciful things happen.

I have looked on the forums and there seems to be so many different, and to me confusing, answers I don't know how to fix it. I'm told I need a new driver but Ubuntu doesn't let me download one.

As you will understand I am absolutely brassed off. I got it to work on Windows XP but that isn't any longer safe to use. So the printer is OK.

Can someone please tell me in plain simple English (I am not at all technical) how to fix this. And if it is not fixable please let me know.

Comment: Keith, What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Did something happen between the time it still worked and it stopped working? (power outage? flood? ... ) ;) Who/what told you you need a new driver?  Please update your question (and tags) to increase the visibility of your problem to a wider community.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a new driver (unsure what version you are currently using now), you can download v4.00 from Canon [here](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG2550.aspx?type=download&language=&os=Linux) (be sure to select the printer driver for Debian, which I see is listed as #5). You can also download scanner drivers from there if you want.

Good luck getting this thing to work for you. I had a cheap Canon printer back when I was using Ubuntu 9.10, and it sucked. (Then again, my parents later got the same printer from me for their Windows machine, and it *still* sucked.) If you do go looking for another printer, I recommend HP, which has very good Linux support, especially if you use HPLIP with it.